# How do I bind several actions to one template in Play! framework?

Tags: templates, playframework

How do I bind several actions to one template in Play! framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `renderTemplate` method. It has the same parameter set as the render() method, passing in the template path as the first argument, but I find using this method makes it clearer in your code what exactly is being done.

```
renderTemplate("templateName", <variable number of parameters>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user render to specify a template:

```
render("ControllerFolder/template.html",param1, param2);
```

Although be sure that's what you want to do, it may bring unexpected behaviour and may increase the cost of maintenance (changes to a method or to the template may impact the rest of the methods).